# Using complex models with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I would like imitate a complex model in knockout.js:

```
function DefInfo(dfirst, dlast) {
    this.dfirst = ko.observable(dfirst);
    this.dlast = ko.observable(dlast);
}

function PaymentViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.pmt = ?? (where pmt.defInfo = DefInfo, pmt.contact = ContactInfo, etc
}
```

and basically what I  would do is pass back json using ko.toJson(pmt);

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to have nested viewModel objects.

Try something like:

```
function DefInfo(dfirst, dlast) {
    this.dfirst = ko.observable(dfirst);
    this.dlast = ko.observable(dlast);
}

function Payment(defInfo, contactInfo) {
    this.defInfo = ko.observable(defInfo);
    this.contactInfo = ko.observable(contactInfo);
}

function PaymentViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.pmt = ko.observable(new Payment(new DefInfo("a", "b"), new ContactInfo()));
}
```

If you don't need them to be observable, you can even do something simple like:

```
function PaymentViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.pmt = {
         defInfo: new DefInfo("a", "b"),
         contact: new ContactInfo()
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I tried the your code and I cannot get the binding right in the html. Here is what I have:

```
   <div class="panel panel-body`">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Defendant Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dfirst">First Name:</label>
        <input data-bind="text: dfirst" type="text" id="dfirst" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dlast">Last Name:</label>
        <input data-bind="text: dlast" type="text" id="dlast" />
    </div>
</fieldset>

<button data-bind="click: makePayment" class="btn btn-default">Make Payment</button>
 </div>
```

When I enter values and click makePayment button - I check the values of pmt.defInfo and they are still blank.

Thanks.

Comment: dfirst needs to be in the context of pmt.defInfo. Try instead of  data-bind="text: dfirst" data-bind="text: pmt.defInfo.dfirst()"